# Basic Acoustic model: Absorption and Interference

Tags: unetstack

The Unetstack handbook refers to Urick's classic book 'The Principles of Sound', pp 105-111, 3rd Ed for transmission loss. There are many causes for absorption described therein. What is accounted for when estimating the absorption in Unetstack?

Second question, how do interference/collisions work in the Basic Acoustic Model, is interference from other nodes treated as added noise or something in that direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Losses taken into account in `BasicAcousticChannel` model:

- Spreading loss
- Frequency-dependent absorption (based on Schulkin & Marsh)

The `BasicAcousticChannel` model treats interference as noise and computes a SINR. The SINR is used to compute the detection probability and the BER for a BPSK modulation with Rician fading and a processing/coding gain. The parameters of the model (e.g. `ricianK`, `pfa`, `processingGain`, `fastFading`, `noiseLevel`, `bandwidth`, `spreading`, `carrierFrequency`, etc) control the details of the gain, fading, etc.